# Mendeley Desktop

Tags: mendeley

I just recently installed Mendeley Desktop on 16.04, and I notice that there are 2 Mendeley Desktops in Ubuntu Software. Does anyone know how to get rid of that bug that makes Ubuntu Software lists 2 Mendeley Desktops?

Thank You.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but could it be that one is the 32bit version and the other one the 64bit version?

Comment: I dont think 2 versions were installed, only Ubuntu Software lists it double. When I open the app, one of the list disappears.